# Error inflating class com.inmobi.ads.InMobiBanner

Tags: inmobi

I followed [the InMobi guidelines](https://support.inmobi.com/monetize/android-guidelines/banner-ads-for-android/) for Android apps step by step but got the following exception from
DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.mainActivity):

> Binary XML file line #670: Binary XML file line #670: Error inflating
>   class com.inmobi.ads.InMobiBanner

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:inmobi="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.inmobi.ads"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView android:text="Ad"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <com.inmobi.ads.InMobiBanner
        android:id="@+id/bannerAdInMobi"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        inmobi:placementId="plid-1526902340491"
        inmobi:refreshInterval="60" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Could anyone offer a tip on how to diagnose it?

Comment: Have you added required dependencies in your build.gradle?

Comment: Yes.  Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no one answered after a month, let me post mine.
InMobil's support has kindly helped me find the culprit - layout inflation before `InMobiSdk.init()`.  An app needs to run `InMobiSdk.init()` before inflating the layout.

My app cannot do this because it uses InMobil ads only under certain conditions (e.g. only the FREE version has ads), so I have removed `com.inmobi.ads.InMobiBanner` from the layout, and add it in Java code when it is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I Solved this problem . just follow these steps ->

Step 1: Declare the variable in your Activity/fragment

```
private lateinit var bannerAd: InMobiBanner
```

Step 2: Initialite InMobiSDK in onCreate()

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    bannerAd= Helper.InitializInMobiAds(requireContext())
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
}
```

Step 3: here is InitializInMobiAds() method in Helper Class

```
 fun InitializInMobiAds(context: Context): InMobiBanner{
        val consentObject = JSONObject()
        try {
            // Provide correct consent value to sdk which is obtained by User
            consentObject.put(InMobiSdk.IM_GDPR_CONSENT_AVAILABLE, false)
            // Provide 0 if GDPR is not applicable and 1 if applicable
            consentObject.put("gdpr", "0")
            // Provide user consent in IAB format
            //  consentObject.put(InMobiSdk.IM_GDPR_CONSENT_IAB, “ << consent in IAB format >> ”)
        } catch (e: JSONException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        InMobiSdk.init(context, "AcountIdHere" , consentObject,  SdkInitializationListener() {
            @Override
            fun onInitializationComplete(error : Error?) {
                if (null != error) {
                    Log.e("", "InMobi Init failed -" + error.message.toString())
                } else {
                    Log.d("", "InMobi Init Successful")
                }
            }
        })

       return  InMobiBanner(context, PLID_here)
    }
```

Step 4: now use .load() method in onCreateView() or in whichever block which runs after onCreate()

```
 binding.adView.load()
```